# tink library com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$ cannot be resolved

Tags: java, encryption, jar, compiler-errors, tink

I recently tried to add the google tink library to eclipse and it always has a "com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$ cannot be resolved" error, I normally never have any problems with adding libraries to my project, and from what I can tell it has something to do with the all key template files since the error only occours when I try to generate a new KeysetHandle with any key template, and the error only starts when i enter in the key template file@ https://github.com/Gameidite/testProject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Protobuf library can generate Java classes for you. You need to find where these .class files have been output to (eg there should be a `GeneratedMessageV3$.class` somewhere) and make sure that they are included on your classpath.  There's presumably somewhere in Eclipse where you can configure where it looks for class files - you'll need to add the generated files there.

If the generated class files don't exist yet you need to figure out what to do to generate them. It might be easier to use Maven or Gradle as suggested in the Tink documentation rather than directly adding things to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably because Eclipse cannot find the protobuf Java runtime. Have you tried adding Tink to your project with Maven or Gradle?